# Bukkit plugin not working?

Tags: java, bukkit

So I recently attempted to make a bukkit plugin for minecraft.
The idea is that this would just be a test plugin to see if I could do it, and apparently I cant. This is the code I came up with

```
package me.glowhoo.BlockChanger;  import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
public class BlockChanger extends JavaPlugin
{
@Override public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(this.getDescription().getName() +
            " has been enabled");
     }
@Override public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(this.getDescription().getName() + " has been disabled");
    } 
@Override public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    /*command: /tpa Glowhoo
     * args.length = 1
     * args[0] = Glowhoo
     * command.getName() = tpa
     */
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("message")){
        if(sender instanceof Player)
        {
            /*ComandSender sender-who sent the command
             * Command cmd- the command that was executed
             * String commandLabel-the command alias that was used
             * String[] args-array of additional arguments
             */
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED +"Hello player!");
        }else
        {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA +"Hello console!");               
        }
     }
    return false;
   }
 }
```

So the problem with this, is that whenever I load up the server, it says the "BlockChanger has been enabled", but then when I try to type the only command it has (message) or /message, Nothing happens and it says it is an unrecognized command and to type /help for info. The problem doesn't end there though, whenever I actually try to get the plugin going, 90% of the time i have a plugin.yml error, which I don't completely understand, but if any of you know anything about this issue, please respond

My plugin.yml file is here (NOTE: this plugin.yml copy actually works, but the command itsself doesn't.) :

```
name: BlockChanger
version: 1.0
main: me.glowhoo.BlockChanger.BlockChanger
description: 
commands: 
message:
description: -no desc-
usage: /message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `plugin.yml` is incorrect. You need to indent `message` under `commands` to define a node. Currently `commands` is a key value for nothing. Change the relevant part to this:

```
commands: 
  message:
    usage: /message
```

Comment: edit: Although it does work now, Whenever I type the command /message, it says "Hello player!" then it also says the usage defined n the plugin.yml. any advice?

Comment: @Peter_Browning: Return true instead of false.

Answer (score 0):

This is some time in the future now, but in case you use this again, when you have a command, you need to return true, else it will tell you it is an incorrect command, even if your .yml/.yaml file is set up right. So here is what you would need to do to make it register your command when called:

```
package me.glowhoo.BlockChanger;  import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
public class BlockChanger extends JavaPlugin
{
@Override public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(this.getDescription().getName() +
            " has been enabled");
     }
@Override public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info(this.getDescription().getName() + " has been disabled");
    } 
@Override public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    /*command: /tpa Glowhoo
     * args.length = 1
     * args[0] = Glowhoo
     * command.getName() = tpa
     */
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("message")){
        if(sender instanceof Player)
        {
            /*ComandSender sender-who sent the command
             * Command cmd- the command that was executed
             * String commandLabel-the command alias that was used
             * String[] args-array of additional arguments
             */
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED +"Hello player!");
        }else
        {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA +"Hello console!");               
        }
        return true;
     }
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to register this class as command executor in onEnable method.

Comment: Your answer could greatly benefit from a code snippet to show what exactly you mean by that